# Making a sidebar menu like mega.nz

Tags: php, html, sidebar

I want to make a sidebar menu like the website mega.nz in php.. like this

[image]

I have tried with this code:

```
function foldersList($folderName = NULL) {

    $return = '';

    $globFolder = ($folderName != NULL ? $folderName : './server/'.$_SESSION['username']) . "/*";


    foreach (glob($globFolder, GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $subFolder) {

        $baseFolder = basename($subFolder) . '';
        // okay let me see
        // call function to check subfolders - don't forget write `/`
        $subFolders = foldersList($subFolder);

        $return .= '<li><a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>' . $baseFolder . '<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>';
        $return .= '<ul class="nav child_menu">';

        // if subfolder exist add to return variable
        $return .= $subFolders != '' ? $subFolders : '';


        $return .= '</ul>';
        $return .= '</li>';
    }

    return $return;
}
```

but the problem is the folder doesn't recognize if inside the folder, have one more folder or have a list of files.
I want, if folder have list of files inside, go to another link
if folder, have one more folder, makes dropdown menu, to show this folder.

Comment: You want to list only folders even if they are empty? Do you get any error while using the function you provided?

Answer (score 0):

To skip empty folders or folders that have only files change the function to:

```
function foldersList($folderName = NULL) {

$return = '';

$globFolder = ($folderName != NULL ? $folderName : './server/'.$_SESSION['username']) . "/*";

$folders = glob($globFolder, GLOB_ONLYDIR);

if(!empty($folders)) {
    foreach ($folders as $subFolder) {

        $baseFolder = basename($subFolder) . '';
        // okay let me see
        // call function to check subfolders - don't forget write `/`
        $subFolders = foldersList($subFolder);

        $return .= '<li><a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>' . $baseFolder . '<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>';
        $return .= '<ul class="nav child_menu">';

        // if subfolder exist add to return variable
        $return .= $subFolders != '' ? $subFolders : '';


        $return .= '</ul>';
        $return .= '</li>';
    }
}

return $return;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution: use a nice plug-in to help you with the tree https://www.jstree.com/

EDIT: added example usage of jstree
Change your function to:

```
function foldersList($folderName = NULL) {

$return = '';

$globFolder = ($folderName != NULL ? $folderName : 
  './server/'.$_SESSION['username']) . "/*";

$folders = glob($globFolder, GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$foldersArray = [];
if(!empty($folders)) {
    foreach ($folders as $subFolder) {
        $baseFolder = basename($subFolder) . '';
        // okay let me see
        // call function to check subfolders - don't forget write `/`
        $subFolders = foldersList($subFolder);


        $foldersArray[] = [
            'text' => $baseFolder,
            'children' => $subFolders
        ];
    }
}
return $foldersArray;}
```

Here is a demo with the output of modified function: https://jsfiddle.net/mrazvan/3sxh0b3c/1/

Create a file where you run the function and echo the json output in one php file:

```
echo json_encode( foldersList('path/to/folder/'));exit;
```

To fetch the output from back end, you can try using the following JS code:

```
$(function() {
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "path/to/phpfile.php",
   success: function(data) {
      $('#tree-container').jstree({
        'plugins' : ['types'],
        'core' : {
          'data' : data,
          'themes' : {
            'variant' : 'medium'
          }
        }
      });
   }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: and i can use php in jstree? to put get name of folders in server?

Comment: Yes you can. You need PHP to fetch folders from back end and provide them in the expected format described in the documentation.